# iPhone - A text in a text

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, text, uikit

I would like to have a text in a text... I mean like in the newspaper: when there is a picture, the text fits and follow the border of the picture.
For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone
look at the pictures... the text follows them!

Is it possible to do that on the iPhone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's called text wrapping.

Comment: The proper page layout term you are looking for is "text wrap". There are generally three types: wrap around the bounding box (always a rectangle), wrap around a shape (i.e. a circle), or a jump where the text doesn't wrap but instead is broken above and below the graphic.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this fairly easily with a `UIWebView` and traditional web techniques.

If you want to have it happen in Cocoa directly, you're going to have to dive into the more advanced CoreText APIs, which will probably be a lot of work.

Comment: mmmhhh... I really wanted it in cocoa! It displays faster.

Comment: You both mean Cocoa Touch if you're talking about programming the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

It's called text wrapping or, in CSS/HTML speak, "floating" an image. The best way to do it is probably to have a UIWebView and programmatically dump HTML and CSS into it.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<img src="IMAGE_URL" style="float:right; margin:6px;" />
<p>My block of arbitrary test. Blah blah blah. Etc.</p>
```

Here's an example of how to use UIWebView with a string of HTML:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-rich-text-using-a-uiwebview

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a link and making an edit. I realized that my initial comment was virtually the same after I made it. :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not use subviews? Have a UIView containing a UIImage and UILabel in case of a static text or a non-editable UITextView in case of dynamic amount of text and set their properties to be aligned to the parent view's boundaries.
If you still want to take the low-level path, google for **CGContextShowTextAtPoint**.
You may also check out this: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/framework/Source/CPTextLayer.h

Comment: how do you align to the parent view's boundaries? I was only able to make the frame a simple rectangle...